# ¿Cómo hacer para que cada una de las dos columnas de una página web pueda ser movida de forma independiente por el usuario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una aplicación ASP.NET MVC 5 que muestra contenido relativo a la historia de mi país. Funciona bien, pero quiero dotarla de un aspecto que facilite comparar el contenido en dos columnas. Quiero dividir la página en dos columnas y poder mover cada columna a voluntad y de manera independiente una de la otra.

Muy agradecido por el consejo que me brinden.

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que estas trabajando con vistas chtml(ya sea con Razor aunque aplica para web forms tambien(.aspx ya que a final son estructuradas en html)) puedes implementar un poco de css y javascript para lograr el efecto deseado.

Te dejo el siguiente enlace a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvelasquezdev/ehjo6xuq/6/)  para que veas una muestra de como utilizo dos columnas y pueda arrastrarlas y colocarlas a mi antojo solo utilizando css y javascript. Saludos

Comment: Muy bonito francisco me será útil. Pero, quisiera precisar mi requerimiento: Mi aplicación presenta en cada columna, mediante AJAX, una serie de párrafos con fechas. Quisiera poder mover cualquiera de las dos columnas solo verticalmente, hacia arriba o hacia abajo con la rueda del ratón, para hacer coincidir horizontalmente párrafos de igual fecha ubicados en columnas diferentes. Soy un programador novato, pero sospecho que con bootstrap se puede resolver el asunto. Aunque por ahora no tengo idea. Mi aplicación utiliza vistas razor .cshtml. Gracias adelantadas a la comunidad.